# Getting a nice circular border on a UIView with dynamic size

Tags: swift, uiview, border

I'm trying to get a nice circular UIView. The obvious way to do it is to set the `view.layer.cornerRadius` to half the width/height (considering of course a square view). That works fine, but "too late". I want my view to be (properly) displayed right when the view controller is presented, however if I try and set the corner radius in `viewWillAppear`, the value is not yet right (as it depends on the screen size) and the border is not a circle (see screenshot). If I set the corner radius in `viewDidAppear`, the value is right but is set only after the view has been actually displayed, which means that it looks "bad" during the presentation animation. Is there a way/method to get the proper value *before* the view is *actually* displayed? When presenting a view controller e.g. by sliding it up, the sizes of the components must have been computing prior to actually starting the animation, when is that?

The screenshot below shows the result when the corner radius is set in `viewWillAppear`. I've designed the view in iPhone 8 mode in IB, and using the iPhone 8+ simulator, so larger screen. The corner radius corresponds to the "original" size in IB, prior to applying constraints.

[image: Screenshot of improper circular border on UIView]

Comment: `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: Yup that did the trick, thanks!